# How to handle web crawlers in Django?

Tags: django, search-engine

I've been getting a lot of errors sent to my e-mail due to web crawlers hitting parts of my site without any request data, and I was wondering what is the best way to handle web crawlers in Django? Should I issue a redirect when I come across an empty QueryDict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider implementing a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) to disallow crawlers from accessing areas of your site that are intended for humans only, such as forms.

Answer (score 1):

I think your views should work with any request, at list return page with message "Incorrect request". 500 is ugly. Are you sure that user don't open page without any request data? "get" method of QueryDict can help with default values.

Answer (score -1):

Well behaved crawlers should only do GET requests. Forms should be anything but GET requests.

Ruby and Rails uses CRUD mapping

```
Create -> POST,
READ -> GET, 
Update -> PUT, 
Delete -> DELETE
```

Only things without additional info should be GET requests.

Comment: "Forms should be anything but GET requests" -> what about `<form method="get"...>`

Comment: Should be discouraged. look at Twitter's homepage and see if there are any GET forms.

Comment: My crawler always uses DELETE... /s

Comment: Thats just cruel and unusual. :)

Comment: Why did you pick Twitter as a model? Why not for example Google (which *does* use GET forms)? In any case, individual examples like these constitute no proof of them being a bad practice. Choosing to use GET or POST should be dictated by method semantics as defined by the RFC2616: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html . In this context, GET forms are perfectly valid.